# I deployed this code, but its taking input only from my device

Tags: python, django, request, voice-recognition, pyaudio

[enter link description here](https://2d66fdfd.ngrok.io/)
After clicking the voice icon start giving voice input. I want to take users output. but when some one click on  the voice icon, it doesn't take input from their device instead take input from my device.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs9WU.png)

```
def voice_recognition(request):

#print("Version is", s_r.__version__)
#print(s_r.Microphone.list_microphone_names())

r = s_r.Recognizer()                                                        
mic = s_r.Microphone(device_index = None)                                  


with mic as source:
    print("Speak after half second!!!!")
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)                    #reduce noise
    audio = r.listen(source, timeout = 30)                #take voice input from the microphone


    #r.recognize_google(audio)                            #to print voice into text
text = r.recognize_google(audio)
```

Comment: Well that is normal. In order to obtain data from a device, you need a connection. For example with Django-channels.

Comment: I don't know django, i just somehow got this by hit and trial methods after 3-4 days of work

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: https://2d66fdfd.ngrok.io/ here's the link

Comment: it will never run. Python runs on server and it has access only to devices on server. Only web browser on user's computer has access to user's microphone and only web browser (and JavaScript) can get user's voice and send it server. But it can be more complex problem.

Comment: Okay thank you, learnt something new today.

Answer (score 1):

The python code runs on your server so it will always invoke your own microphone. To get user input you can use javascript to record audio and send it to server.
https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

Comment: No if you want to deploy it on the web you need to do it on client side(i.e using JS).
There are a few tutorials that may help you.
https://blog.addpipe.com/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/